# Can't delete stack in status DELETE_FAILED and the retain resources is empty. What should I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to delete a stack create using AWS Cloud Formation. However, the AWS is not showing the error cause and can't (apparently) do anything to resolve it by myself.

I think my mistake was a typo on the Cloud Formation file and the AWS can't recover it. Instead of use this notation to the ClusterName:

```
Service:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
    Cluster:
      !Ref ClusterName
```

I added a `-`:

```
Service:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
    Cluster:
      - !Ref ClusterName
```

The probably result of this was a `CREATE_FAILED` with the Status Reason **Internal Failure** when creating the Service.

When I try to delete it, the status is `DELETE_FAILED` with the same Status Reason: **Internal Failure**. I can't fix this typo because I can't make a new changeset on the Cloud Formation with the status `DELETE FAILED`.

When the AWS show the option for "resources to retain", to skip the problematic resource, the list of options is empty:

**[image: strong text]**

I tried to "force" the retain resources, but I receive the same error on AWS:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name service-name --retain-resources Service
```

The described Service result, using the follow command:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --stack-name service-name --logical-resource-id Service
```

Is:

```
{
    "StackResourceDetail": {
        "StackName": "service-name",
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/service-name/a1b35890-41d5-13eb-c129-0er5kko75597",
        "LogicalResourceId": "Service",
        "ResourceType": "AWS::ECS::Service",
        "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2020-09-27T12:00:06.175000+00:00",
        "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
        "ResourceStatusReason": "Internal Failure",
        "Metadata": "{}",
        "DriftInformation": {
            "StackResourceDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
        }
    }
}
```

What are my options now?

Comment: Have you looked in to the cloud trail > Event history for the exact cause of the failure?

Comment: @SRATH, I found in the Cloud Trail the `DeleteStack` and `CreateStack` events. But both not shows any detail about the error.

Comment: Does the service in question exist in the ECS console? If not, you can create one with the expected name and re-try deletion or retention from CFN.